# Is there a way to modify/customize the fields shown in the Group Contacts Window?

Tags: contacts, groups, searchkit

Is there a way to modify/customize the fields shown in the Group Contacts Window?
When we're looking at the Contacts in a Group, under  >Contacts >Manage Groups, is there a way to modify this view/fields shown in this window?
For instance:

1. email address is truncated
2. would like to see the Employer of the Contact (Organization linked to Individual Contact)

Comment: What CMS are you likely to use?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can build your own using the rapidly-evolving [Search Kit](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/search-kit/).

For example, [try this on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22display_name%22,%22employer_id.display_name%22,%22Contact_Email_contact_id_01.email%22,%22Contact_Phone_contact_id_01.phone%22,%22Contact_Address_contact_id_01.city%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Address%20AS%20Contact_Address_contact_id_01%22,%22LEFT%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_Address_contact_id_01.contact_id%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_Address_contact_id_01.is_primary%22,%22%3D%22,true%5D%5D,%5B%22Email%20AS%20Contact_Email_contact_id_01%22,%22LEFT%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_Email_contact_id_01.contact_id%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_Email_contact_id_01.is_primary%22,%22%3D%22,true%5D%5D,%5B%22Phone%20AS%20Contact_Phone_contact_id_01%22,%22LEFT%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_Phone_contact_id_01.contact_id%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_Phone_contact_id_01.is_primary%22,%22%3D%22,true%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D)

(screenshot added for posterity)

[image]

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you take one more step, then the solution is easier. When you click on Contacts as you describe you should see an Advanced Search link to the right
[image]

OR you could simply initiate your search via Adv Search and choose the required Group via the Groups field.

Then, in order to see different columns, you need to create a Profile that has the fields in it that you want (set the Profile to work for Search), and then via the Adv Search screen use the **Views for Display Contacts** to select your profile

[image]

More documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/#views-for-display-contacts

Comment: Thank you! We do already use the search functions. The question is more geared toward having the flexibility to define what columns show in certain windows where there are many fields/details present. From a UI perspective, each company has their own "preferences", and it would help to be able to customize your own 'view' (similar to the Display Preferences).

Comment: I think building a profile, setting that to be your default 'search result' view is the only option via the UI, and will only apply via Adv Search. Otherwise you will need to customise some of the templates. but now i am not sure if by 'company' you mean 'client' or something else

Comment: Thank you, "company" = Yes, I mean client.